# Minestom (Minecraft) water bucket placing

Tags: java, server, minecraft, minestom

I am creating a Minecraft server using minestom which is a server building library, it had so no code and you have to make everything yourself. So im trying to make it so players can place water but it doesnt work sometimes. If im falling and place it then it gets placed client side but not server side sometimes, when its placed server side it says "placed block" in the chat.

```java
        globalEventHandler.addListener(PlayerUseItemOnBlockEvent.class, event -> {
            final Player player = event.getPlayer();
            if (event.getItemStack().getMaterial() != Material.WATER_BUCKET) {
                return;
            }

            if (player.getInstance().getBlock(new Vec(event.getPosition().x(),
                    event.getPosition().y(),
                    event.getPosition().z())) == Block.IRON_BLOCK
                    && event.getBlockFace().normalY() == 1) {

                Point placedPos = event.getPosition();
                placedPos.withX(placedPos.x() + event.getBlockFace().normalX());
                placedPos.withY(placedPos.y() + event.getBlockFace().normalY());
                placedPos.withZ(placedPos.z() + event.getBlockFace().normalZ());

                player.getInstance().setBlock(placedPos, Block.WATER);

                player.sendMessage("placed water");
            }

            player.getInventory().update();
        });
```

Video - Ignore the platform disappearing, bug that I know how to fix but havent just yet but that also only happens when the water is placed server side too
https://youtu.be/njH58gbXPlE

Comment: Can you expand on *it doesn't work sometimes* ? What happens that makes you think that it doesn't work? Is your code throwing an exception? Granted I'm not a Minecraft player, nonetheless I did not understand what you are trying to demonstrate with your 28 second video.

Comment: Oops sorry, It seems to not work when im far away and the server client doesnt say they used the water bucket for some reason. thats what ive got from my testing anyway

Comment: well it is meant to place the water server side, when that happens a message saying "placed block" appears in chat. sometimes it is only placed client side and no message appears in chat, when this happens the water stays after you teleport back to the top platform. there are no errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe on the look vector is the next tick’s look vector for placing water, but the server hasn’t gotten this new look vector so it uses the old one